# python 2.6 import error when invoking python file

Tags: python

I have the following error when i run a python file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "MySimulation.py", line 14, in <module>
    from random import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/random.py", line 48, in <module>
    from binascii import hexlify as _hexlify
ImportError: No such file or directory
```

Have you a solution?

Comment: How did you install Python? The `binascii` module is typically statically linked to Python, so there should not be circumstances in a working install where it would not be available.

Comment: (On a separate note, best practices dictate never using `import *`.)

Answer (score 2):

From `help(binascii)`.

```
Help on built-in module binascii:

NAME
    binascii - Conversion between binary data and ASCII

FILE
    (built-in)

CLASSES
    exceptions.Exception(exceptions.BaseException)
        Error
        Incomplete

    class Error(exceptions.Exception)
     |  Method resolution order:
     |      Error
     |      exceptions.Exception
     |      exceptions.BaseException
     |      __builtin__.object
     |
     |  Data descriptors defined here:
     |
     |  __weakref__
```

`binascii` is a builtin module. Your Python library seems to be installed in `/usr/local/lib`. So, I am guessing you have built it yourself. Are you sure, it built the `binascii` module successfully? That could be the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you compiled Python from source it's possible to create a working Python that doesn't have a `binascii` module.  I suspect the output when you build Python had something like this:

```
Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not found:
_bsddb             _tkinter           bsddb185        
sunaudiodev                                           
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.

Failed to build these modules:
_ctypes            _curses            _curses_panel   
_hashlib           _multiprocessing   _sqlite3        
_ssl               binascii           bz2             
dbm                gdbm               readline        
zlib
```

You probably also see `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz`.

The problem is that `binascii` depends on `zlib`.  You need to make sure that `zlib` is found by the linker:

Answer (score -3):

Install `binascii`. If it's installed, ensure that your `PYTHONPATH` includes the location it is installed to.

Comment: Well, binascii is a builtin module, so it should be there.  It's one of the ones that can sometimes fail to build, though, so my bet's that's what happened.

Comment: @NounouNou As mentioned by DSM, if you are installing python from source, you will have to try to re-build `binascii`.

Comment: when i rebuild i got the following error:

Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not found:
_bsddb             _curses            _curses_panel
_sqlite3           _ssl               _tkinter
bsddb185           bz2                linuxaudiodev
nis                ossaudiodev        readline
spwd               sunaudiodev
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.

Comment: @NounouNou I am not going to walk you through building python.